# using regex to make a number of checks

Tags: php, regex, string

I am very confused by regex expression checks. I am trying to make several checks on two different strings in php. The first string must be 3-8 characters long, begin with a lowercase letter, and consist entirely of lowercase and the second must be 6-12 characters long, begin with a number, and end with any character that is not a letter or number. So if I had $first = "ttyl45" and $second = "6ttyl56*" These would pass the checks. I just don't know how to go about doing this because regex is very confusing to me I looked all over the internet but I'm still stuck

Comment: Check out http://regex101.com. It's a great resource for regex beginners and experts.

Comment: thank you that is very helpful!

Comment: First one: `^[a-z]{3,8}$` Second one: `^[0-9].{4,10}[^a-zA-Z0-9]$`

Comment: `$first` does not *"consist entirely of lowercase"*.

Answer (score 1):

You need two separated patterns to check `$first` and `$second`. Try this:

```
$first = "ttyl45";
$second = "6ttyl56*";

if (preg_match("/^[a-z][a-z0-9]{2,7}$/", $first) && preg_match("/^[0-9].{4,10}[^a-zA-Z0-9]$/", $second) ) {
   echo "checks";
} else {
   echo "not checks";
}
```